# I am trying to show a string in label with diffrent color how to perform this..?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0

```
IDE = Visual Studio 2010  
Language = c# .net   
Technology = windows forms application
```

Hi,
i am having 3 labels

Label1 details:

```
label1.text = "Team1";  
label1.forecolor = Color.yellow;
```

Label2 details:

```
label2.text = "Team1";  
label2.forecolor = Color.green;
```

Label3 details:

```
label3.text = "Team1";  
label3.forecolor = Color.grey;
```

Now, What i am trying is this :

```
label4.text = "Match between " + label1.text+ " and " +label2.text+ " at " +label3.text         ;
```

But the output of this i am getting all the labels in same color  which is set to     label4.
and i want it to be displayed in different color.

I have tried this solution to put the different labels in form but it is getting     overlapped.

so is there any way to concatenate labels..?

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 2):

If you are inclined, you can create a UserControl and override its `OnPaint` function to draw these 3 chunks of text in different colors using GDI+. All it would take is a simple `DrawString` call.

```
e.Graphics.DrawString("LabelText", this.Font, Brushes.Red, new Point(100, 100));
```

You can then expose 3 public properties to control the 3 chunks of text and optionally 3 color properties to control chunk's color. Note that you need to create `SolidBrush` from those colors in `OnPaint` because that's what `DrawString` expects, like this:

```
using(SolidColorBrush br = new SolidColorBrush(mColor1)
    e.Graphics.DrawString("LabelText", this.Font, br, new Point(100, 100));
```

Full code:

```
public partial class MultiColorLabel : Label
{
    public MultiColorLabel()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public string Text1 { get; set; }
    public string Text2 { get; set; }
    public string Text3 { get; set; }

    public Color Color1 { get; set; }
    public Color Color2 { get; set; }
    public Color Color3 { get; set; }

    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnPaint(e);

        var g = e.Graphics;

        e.Graphics.DrawString("Match between ", this.Font, Brushes.Black, 0, 0);
        var sz = g.MeasureString("Match between ", this.Font).Width;

        using (SolidBrush sb = new SolidBrush(Color1))
            e.Graphics.DrawString(Text1, this.Font, sb, sz, 0);

        sz += g.MeasureString(Text1, this.Font).Width;

        e.Graphics.DrawString(" and ", this.Font, Brushes.Black, sz, 0);
        sz += g.MeasureString(" and ", this.Font).Width;

        using (SolidBrush sb = new SolidBrush(Color2))
            e.Graphics.DrawString(Text2, this.Font, sb, sz, 0);

        sz += g.MeasureString(Text2, this.Font).Width;

        e.Graphics.DrawString(" at ", this.Font, Brushes.Black, sz, 0);
        sz += g.MeasureString(" at ", this.Font).Width;

        using (SolidBrush sb = new SolidBrush(Color3))
            e.Graphics.DrawString(Text3, this.Font, sb, sz, 0);
    }
}
```

Here's the snapshot:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Label.Text is only return a string not any format. So all of text here will have the same color of label4. You need add your labels in a pannel control instead.

Answer (score 0):

**Problem :** you are just assigning the `Text` of other `Label` controls, so it only displays the `Text` but other properties like (`ForeColor`) wont be applied.

**Solution :** in my opinion i don't think that displaying multiple colurs for single `Label` String is possible directly.

So you can either develop your own `User Control` to dispaly Text in multiple controls.

or

You can use `RichTextBox` control.

Answer (score -1):

Text` will not return a the whole label, it will only return the text(string) of that label. If you want to do what you wanted go and read some posts about Graphics.